# Disable shipping method based on zip, how to get zip in tpl

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I have a shipping method with a certain name. If the zip code of the delivery address is NOT 1234, the selection of that shipping method should be disabled.

I think this could be done within themes\classic\templates\checkout_partials\steps\shipping.tpl with adding a smarty tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 carriere-name-container{if $carrier.logo} col-md-8{/if}">
<span class="h6 carrier-name {if $address.zip == 1234}not-allowed{/if}">{$carrier.name} </span>
</div>
```

However, I'm unsure how to get the ZIP code exactly in the tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put {debug} on tpl's top and you will watch available tpl_vars.